# How can I study Z-transform, Laplace transform, Fourier transform?

Tags: reference-request, physics, laplace-transform, fourier-transform, z-transform

I am a student majoring in electrical engineering.
Actually, I know those transformaton formulas.
However, I do not grasp that physical meaning.
So, I made a decision to study them with fundamental textbook.
Can someone recommend which book gives me their physical meaning in a detail? I surely want the book to have concise and rigorous mathematical explanation.

Comment: A good way of understanding the Fourier transform (in all of its various incarnations) is that we are changing basis to a special basis which consists of eigenvectors of a shift operator. Because shift operators preserve norms, they are unitary, hence normal. Thus, the spectral theorem from linear algebra leads us to expect (or at least hope) that the eigenvectors of a shift operator form an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differential Equations with boundry-value problems seventh Edition by Dennis G.Zill and Michael R.Cullen. This book is very nice I had this as course book when I studied Signal and Systems course.

http://a.co/4a8ZYmD

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I saw this answer finally.. now!! I will buy this book. Thanks :) (but so expensive :()